# Filtering of arrays doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, filter

I'm having trouble filtering data in Javascript correctly. In my example var1 = 20, var2 = 10, var3 = 30, var4 = 40. This is my code:

```
var variables = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4'],
values = [20, 10, 30, 40],
filter = ['var1', 'var3'],
result = values.filter((_, i) => filter.includes(variables[i]));
console.log(result); // Output =>[20, 30]
```

Now the filtering pushes a value each time the index represents a value that exists in the filter array. I want to be able to move var1 and 20 to index 2, and var3 to index 0 without it affecting the order of the result. Basically I want it to follow the order of the filter-array, so always [20, 30] for this example. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of building your result starting from `values` and filtering down, start from `filter` and map to your result:

```js
var variables = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4'],
    values = [20, 10, 30, 40],
    filter = ['var3', 'var1'],
    result = filter.map((variable) => values[variables.indexOf(variable)]);

console.log(result);
```

However, I would strongly recommend you avoid this pattern of tightly-coupled arrays of strings entirely, and instead just use an object, which is purpose-built for this kind of data structure:

```js
var values = {
  var1: 20,
  var2: 10,
  var3: 30,
  var4: 40
};

var filter = ['var3', 'var1'];

var result = filter.map((key) => values[key]);

console.log(result);
```